# How to check if the same letter is used more than once in a word (hangman project, javascript)

Tags: javascript, prompt

I have almost finished the javascript logic for my personal hangman project i am creating. One of the final issues i am having is getting the program to recognize if the same letter is used in the "chosen word". For example, when "ninja" is selected as the "chosen word", and the user selects "n", i would like my counter variable to recognize that there are two "n's", and add 2 to the score instead of one.

My code thus far:

```
var secretWords = ["batman", "Donkey kong", "ninja", 
"programming"];
 var chosenWord = secretWords[Math.floor(Math.random()*secretWords.length)]; 
var guesses = 8;
 console.log(chosenWord);
 var letters = chosenWord.length;
var counter = 0;
var gameOver = guesses === 0;
console.log(guesses);
console.log(counter);


while(guesses !== 0){
const guess = prompt("GUESS A LETTER")
var guessLowerCase = guess.toLowerCase();
var isGuessedLetterInWord = 
chosenWord.includes(guessLowerCase);
if (isGuessedLetterInWord) {
alert('nice'); counter ++;

 } else {
alert('wrong'); guesses --;

}
}

if(counter === chosenWord.length){
 alert("You Win!!");
}

if (guesses === 0){
alert("LOSER!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple hack would be to split the string by letter and count.

```
let occurances = chosenWord.split(guessLowerCase).length - 1
```

Or you could use regular expression to search for all occurances:

```
let occurances = [...chosenWord.matchAll(new RegExp(guessLowerCase, 'g'))].length
```